# How to convert array of nested objects to objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, functional-programming

I have got array of nested array of objects . I want to get only Permission objects from data and I need to convert data array to permission objects .

```
 "data":[
       {
          "Book":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             },

          ]
       },
       {
          "Articles":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
         ]
       },
       {
          "Journals":[

             {
                "label":"Can Upload",
                "value":"can_upload"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Download",
                "value":"can_download"
             }
          ]
       },

       {
          "Permission":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

I am trying to get permission objects from list of my data objects. I am using filter method for geting Permission array and want to convert permission objects, but I got nested arrays . where is the problem?

```
let dataPer = data.permissions.filter(item=>item.Permission).map(item=>item.Permission)

console.log(dataPer)
```

My accepted output would be :

```
 let output= {

       Permission:{
         can_view:"can_view",
       can_create:"can_create"

       }
   }
```

Comment: accepted output is syntactically invalid.

Comment: The "_accepted output_" is not a valid object. Please at least do some research and testing before posting a question.

Comment: I edited . sorry it was mistake

Comment: Can you give a proper example of the kind of output you want ?

Comment: [{
          "Permission":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             }
          ]
       }
    ] I want to get output from this. my output would be :  let output= {
can_view:"can_view",
           can_create:"can_create"

       }

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try something like this :

```js
 let data=[
       {
          "Book":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Articles":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             }
         ]
       },
       {
          "Journals":[

             {
                "label":"Can Upload",
                "value":"can_upload"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Download",
                "value":"can_download"
             }
          ]
       },

       {
          "Permission":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             }
          ]
       }
    ];
let myPermissionObjects = [];
let permissionConvert = ()=>{
for(let current in data)
    for(let currentObject in data[current])
      for(let currentResult in data[current][currentObject])
        myPermissionObjects.push(data[current][currentObject][currentResult]);

};
permissionConvert();
console.log(myPermissionObjects);
```

if i understood your problem correctly

for the object permission only :

```js
let data=[
           {
              "Book":[
                 {
                    "label":"Can View",
                    "value":"can_view"
                 },
                 {
                    "label":"Can Create",
                    "value":"can_create"
                 }
              ]
           },
           {
              "Articles":[
                 {
                    "label":"Can View",
                    "value":"can_view"
                 }
             ]
           },
           {
              "Journals":[

                 {
                    "label":"Can Upload",
                    "value":"can_upload"
                 },
                 {
                    "label":"Can Download",
                    "value":"can_download"
                 }
              ]
           },

           {
              "Permission":[
                 {
                    "label":"Can View",
                    "value":"can_view"
                 },
                 {
                    "label":"Can Create",
                    "value":"can_create"
                 }
              ]
           }
        ];
    let myPermissionObjects = [];
    let permissionConvert = ()=>{
    for(let current in data)
        for(let currentObject in data[current].Permission)
          myPermissionObjects.push( data[current].Permission[currentObject]);


    };
    permissionConvert();
    console.log(myPermissionObjects);
    let onePermission = [];
    for(let next in myPermissionObjects)
    {
    onePermission["Permission"]=myPermissionObjects[next];
    console.log(myPermissionObjects[next]);
    }
```

Comment: I only need 
       {
          "Permission":[
             {
                "label":"Can View",
                "value":"can_view"
             },
             {
                "label":"Can Create",
                "value":"can_create"
             }
          ]
       } this data

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `reduce` function, like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    Book: [
      {
        label: "Can View",
        value: "can_view"
      },
      {
        label: "Can Create",
        value: "can_create"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Articles: [
      {
        label: "Can View",
        value: "can_view"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Journals: [
      {
        label: "Can Upload",
        value: "can_upload"
      },
      {
        label: "Can Download",
        value: "can_download"
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    Permission: [
      {
        label: "Can View",
        value: "can_view"
      },
      {
        label: "Can Create",
        value: "can_create"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

--

```
function getPermissionList() {
  const list = data
    .filter(item => item.Permission)[0]
    .Permission.reduce((list, item) => {
      list.push({ [item.label]: item.value });
      return list;
    }, {});
  return Object.assign({}, list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , but is it best for my code

```
let dataPer = data.permissions.filter(item=>item.Permission)
const result = Object.assign({},dataPer)

let res = result[0].Permission.map(item=>{
  return {
    [item.value]:item.value
  }
})
const obj = Object.assign({},res)
console.log(obj[0].can_view)
```

Comment: Depending on the operations you want to do with your object, yes it might be.